# How do I set up Typescript to use the JSDoc types if it exists

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

How do I set up Typescript to use the JSDoc types if it exists?

I have my function annotating the parameter and return type but typescript still as any. How can I set up Typescript to define my parameter and return types by its JSDoc if a JSDoc exists?  ([Visual Studio Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajTEy.png))

```js
/**
 * Creates arrow icon's class name to rotate it upon its x axis.
 * 
 * Arrow icon communicates to the user that they can expand or collapse the filter.
 *
 * @param {boolean} isOpen If the filter is open so that it can be viewed.
 * @returns {string} The class name for the arrow icon.
 */
const arrowClassName = (isOpen) =>
  isOpen ? styles.arrowIcon : `${styles.arrowIcon} ${styles.expanded}`;
```

Error displayed on `isOpen`: `Parameter 'isOpen' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`

Comment: is your code in a JS file ? (it's required)

Comment: no, it is in a `tsx` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Typescript requires](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html) files to be in Javascript (`*.js`) to support most the of JSDoc annotations.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I'm not seeing where it requires it.  Is this the line which you are pointing to?  


`The list below outlines which constructs are currently supported when using JSDoc annotations to provide type information in JavaScript files.`

Comment: Yes, this is it. You can also see a little furter  that documentation annotations only are supported in both `ts` & `js`.

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as answered !